# Can I flash a different BIOS than what was shipped with my PC?

Tags: bios

I have a laptop that won't boot off of a CD or USB. Can I flash a different BIOS than what my Dell Inspiron 15R was shipped with? I think that I might get better luck with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the BIOS is suited to the drive then you can flash it.   Dells are good this way, you can typically find a "service tag" on the back of the laptop, enter it in to the appropriate place on the Dell website and see if there is a new BIOS (or new drivers) you can use to upgrade things.

Also, depending on the age of your laptop, you should be able to call Dell and speak to them.